# Install Pass on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, apt, package-management, password

I am trying to install:

```
 sudo apt-get install pass
```

from https://www.passwordstore.org/.

But I get the error:

```
sudo apt-get install pass
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package pass
```

How to fix this error?

When I try:

```
apt policy pass
N: Unable to locate package pass
```

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=pass&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all shows it's found in 'universe', have you enabled that?  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

Comment: @guiverc The universe is enabled for all sources but pass is still not working

Comment: Something is wrong with your sources list. Did you do `sudo apt update` after adding universe?

Comment: @OrganicMarble I tried now: still after the sudo apt update, I get: pass

Command 'pass' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install pass

Comment: I would suggest you `sudo apt update` and read the output from the command. If you're not familiar with reading that output looking for issues/errors (invalid or missing sources, a *out-of-date* mirror used etc), you can provide it for us to look at, but I suspect you'll see the issue there.  The command `apt-cache policy pass` I would expect would show where it will come from, however in your case your issue is likely sources and thus `sudo apt update` will reveal problems.

Comment: Please run `sudo apt-add-repository universe ; sudo apt-get update ; sudo apt-get install pass` and  then share output of `which pass` and `/usr/bin/pass --version` .